# activerecord-multi-tenant / acts_as_tenant and Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin, acts-as-tenant

Anyone managed to get this to work with ActiveAdmin?  It seems that with AA you can only access the records that your normal user was last logged in under (i.e. AR is still scoping the DB calls with the last tenant).  I know there is the `MultiTenant.without do` but it's not clear you can integrate that with AA.

I thought about adding a `current_user.admin_user?` to the model tenant definition but not sure if that is right or would work.

I want to access ALL my tenant data from AA without having to switch tenants etc.

Comment: Did you find a solution?

Comment: I forgot I posted this - I think (need to confirm) that I had basic auth for AA and not this `devise_for :admin_users, ActiveAdmin::Devise.config`. Once I added admin_users then the issue want away.